# Windows Ping deve retornar somente os valores de resposta

Tags: windows, batch

Estou fazendo um script e preciso que o **Ping** ou **Fping** no windows retorne somente os valores do tempo, sem o *ms*, tipo:

```
ping 8.8.8.8

Disparando 8.8.8.8 com 32 bytes de dados:
Resposta de 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 tempo=29ms TTL=58
Resposta de 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 tempo=26ms TTL=58
Resposta de 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 tempo=21ms TTL=58
Resposta de 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 tempo=29ms TTL=58

Estatísticas do Ping para 8.8.8.8:
    Pacotes: Enviados = 4, Recebidos = 4, Perdidos =
             perda),
Aproximar um número redondo de vezes em milissegundo
    Mínimo = 21ms, Máximo = 29ms, Média = 26ms
```

Ao invés desta saída, preciso somente de :

```
29
26
21
29
```

Consigo fazer isso em um bat?

Answer (score 4):

Faça o seguinte:

```bash
@echo off
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%i in ('ping -n 1 bing.com^|find "ms"') do set "tempo=%%i"
echo.%tempo%
PAUSE
```

O resultado deve ser semelhante há isto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora para capturar apenas os valores desejados, você pode fazer:

```bash
@echo off
for /f "tokens=6* delims==ms" %%i in ('ping -n 4 bing.com^|find "tempo"') do echo %%i
PAUSE
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A sintaxe do laço `For` pode ser encontrada [**aqui**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Apesar de não ser totalmente o que você procura, recentemente eu fiz com a ajuda deste mesmo site um bat que além de registrar a latência em tempo real o mesmo mostra a latência máxima e mínima registrada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
@Echo Off
Title Ping - Humberto Freitas
Color 1f
mode con:lines=12 cols=39
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
Set "IPServidor=104.16.22.33"
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
set "lowPing=999"
set "highPing=  0"


Echo        ÚÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄ¿
Echo        ³ ¯ Calculando...       ³
Echo        ÀÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÙ
Echo.
Echo        ÚÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄ¿
Echo        ³ ¯ Calculando...       ³
Echo        ÀÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÙ
Echo.
Echo        ÚÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄ¿
Echo        ³ ¯ Calculando...       ³
Echo        ÀÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÙ


:doPing

set "ping="

for /f "tokens=9" %%a in ('
ping -n 2 "%IPServidor%" ^|find "ms,"
') do for /f "delims=m " %%b in ("%%a") do set "ping=%%~b"

Cls

if not defined ping  (
Echo.
Echo.
Echo.
Echo.
Echo  ÚÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄ¿
echo  ³ ¯ O servidor nÆo est  respodendo! ³
Echo  ÀÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÙ
Echo.
Echo.
Echo.
Echo.
goto :doPing
)

Cls

Set ping=   %ping%
Set ping=%ping:~-3%
if %ping% gtr %highPing% set "highPing=%ping%"
if %ping% lss %lowPing%  set "lowPing=%ping%"

Echo        ÚÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄ¿
Echo        ³ ¯ Ping atual:  %ping%ms  ³
Echo        ÀÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÙ
Echo.
Echo        ÚÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄ¿
Echo        ³ ¯ Ping m¡nimo: %lowPing%ms  ³
Echo        ÀÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÙ
Echo.
Echo        ÚÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄ¿
Echo        ³ ¯ Ping m ximo: %highPing%ms  ³
Echo        ÀÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÙ

Goto :doPing
```